# Change Super User Account Details

Tags: civimember

The super user email address is pointing to someone who is no longer in my company. I need to change this - how would I do so?

Comment: hi Jaye - you may need to provide a bit more info. Are you using Spark (which is a hosted version of civicrm with slightly limited capabilities)?

Comment: Hi - it is not hosted to the best of my knowledge. I'm somewhat non-technical so I might not completely understand the options here. I use it through Wordpress and can see a database in cPanel that appears to belong to Civi. I hope that helps

Comment: @Jaye Gaff CiviCRM's user accounts come from WordPress, so this is actually a WordPress question.  You should be able to go to your WP dashboard and select **Users** from the left nav, find the admin account and change the email.  However, since this question isn't CiviCRM-specific, it's likely to get closed or moved to the WP Stack Exchange.